# Como hacer para que funcione el método toFixed al incorporarlo al objeto e instanciándolo en los arrays en un algoritmo de Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, javascript-objeto, decimal

En este código no hallo la manera como hacer que funcione el método toFixed, pues he intentado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido, desde colocarlo en el valor de la propiedad precio en el constructor del objeto Viajes, tal como está, hasta colocarlo en las funciones flecha y nada, no me lo toma. Incluso pensé que había conflicto con parseFloat y probé eliminando esto y tampoco lo tomó. El tema es que debería funcionar para que al mostrar los resultados de las operaciones por consola en los distintos arrays, sus precios aparezcan con solo dos decimales.

```
class Viajes {
  constructor(viaje, precio, duracion){
  this.viaje = viaje
  this.precio = parseFloat(precio).toFixed(2)
  this.duracion = duracion
  this.sold = false
  }
  addIVA(){
      this.precio = this.precio * 1.16
  }
  }
  const stock = []
  
  stock.push (new Viajes("Santo Domingo", 9327.87, "Vacaciones")),
  stock.push (new Viajes("Cancun", 1762.76, "Ida y vuelta")),
  stock.push (new Viajes("Buenos Aires", 8790.13, "Fin de semana")),
  stock.push (new Viajes("Barranquilla", 8239.57, "Vacaciones"))
  
  for(const Viajes of stock) Viajes.addIVA()
  console.log(stock)
  
  const vacaciones = stock.filter( tipo => tipo.duracion === "Vacaciones");
  
  console.log(vacaciones)
  
  const undia = stock.filter( tipo => tipo.duracion === "Ida y vuelta");
  
  console.log(undia)
  
  const barato = stock.filter( tipo => tipo.precio <= 1000);
  
  console.log(barato)
  
  const alto = stock.filter( tipo => tipo.precio <= 10000);
  
  console.log(alto)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema esta en la funcion `addIVA()`.  Agrega `toFixed()` dentro de esa funcion.  Quedaria asi:

```js
class Viajes {
  constructor(viaje, precio, duracion){
  this.viaje = viaje
  this.precio = parseFloat(precio).toFixed(2)
  this.duracion = duracion
  this.sold = false
  }
  addIVA(){
      this.precio = (this.precio * 1.16).toFixed(2)
  }
  }
  const stock = []
  
  stock.push (new Viajes("Santo Domingo", 9327.87, "Vacaciones")),
  stock.push (new Viajes("Cancun", 1762.76, "Ida y vuelta")),
  stock.push (new Viajes("Buenos Aires", 8790.13, "Fin de semana")),
  stock.push (new Viajes("Barranquilla", 8239.57, "Vacaciones"))
  
  for(const Viajes of stock) Viajes.addIVA()
  console.log(stock)
  
  const vacaciones = stock.filter( tipo => tipo.duracion === "Vacaciones");
  
  console.log(vacaciones)
  
  const undia = stock.filter( tipo => tipo.duracion === "Ida y vuelta");
  
  console.log(undia)
  
  const barato = stock.filter( tipo => tipo.precio <= 1000);
  
  console.log(barato)
  
  const alto = stock.filter( tipo => tipo.precio <= 10000);
  
  console.log(alto)
```